# Can all usages of `forSome` be replaced by an equivalent usage of `_`?

Tags: generics, scala, types, existential-type

For instance, `List[T] forSome { type T }` is equivalent to `List[_]`, but is this true for every possible usage of `forSome` or are there cases where `forSome` cannot be replaced by an equivalent of the second syntax?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, not all usages can be thus converted. Something like this (thanks to *retronym*, below, who should be getting the upvotes on this one)

```
def foo(xs: Map[T, T] forSome { type T})
```

The point here is that I can use the existential in more than one place but *it is the same existential*. Obviously, if you used wildcards, you would be referring to different existentials

Comment: In this example; no. To be honest, I'm not 100% sure it's valid syntax and haven't had the chance to check. But I have seen examples along similar lines

Comment: Indeed, I just tried it with scala 2.9.1 and **it does not compile** ! Could you please fix it, I cannot do it for you, I've never used/needed `forSome` construct.

Comment: Fixed along the lines suggested by retronym

Answer (score 14):

`_` in this context is the "Placeholder Syntax for Existential Types", described in 3.2.10 of the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

The name sounds a lot like another use of `_`, "Placeholder Syntax for Anonymous Functions". This shorthand can't be used for all functions. For example:

```
(a: A) => f(g(a))
f(g(_: A)) // WRONG, this means f((a: A) => g(a))
```

We can construct a similar example for existentials, which can't be represented `_`:

```
F[G[A]] forSome { type A }
F[G[_]] // WRONG, this means F[G[A] forSome { type A }]
```

Side note: existentials are **not** the type level analog of value level functions. That would be:

```
({type l[A] = F[G[A]])#l
```

In fact it's a pity that Scala uses the underscore for existentials, rather than type level functions.

**UPDATE**

Let me frame [@oxbow_lakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16853/oxbow-lakes)' answer in the same way:

```
(a: A) => h(a, a)
h(_, _) // WRONG, this means (a, b) => f(a, b)

H[A, A] forSome { type A }
H[_, _] // WRONG, this means H[A, B] forSome { type A; type B }
```

Comment: What is difference between F[G[A]] forSome { type A } and F[G[A] forSome { type A }]?